# How can import.io write crawled data to a file in real time

Tags: web-crawler, import.io

I currently have a crawler set up in import.io which crawls through a very large number of pages (tens of thousands). Once this crawler is finished, I try to view the data only to see that it has all been lost, which I assume is due to sheer volume. Is there a way to set up my crawler so that it writes the data to a file on my hard drive in real time as the data is collected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can , before you start to crawl there is an option just below the links area [image]

1 - **Save Stream** is where you choose the file name and where to save , also makesure you add .csv or .json to the file name

2 -**Stream Type** you choose the output type from a dropdown .